# JS: Can I add an EventListener in a contructor method of a class to call a method of the same class?

Tags: javascript, class, scope, addeventlistener

I want to create a DOM element that changes its color when clicked on. The DOM object is appended to `document.body` by the `draw()` method that belongs to the `Rectangle` class.

I want the Rectangle `constructor()` method to add the `EventListener("click", ...)` to the object itself, but it can't call the `select()` method, which also belongs to `Rectangle` class.

I get the error message `select() is not a function`. I can't write `addEventListener("click", this.select(true))` because for some reason, the rectangle is already selected when the HTML document is loaded.

On the other hand, when I try `addEventListener("click", function() { this.select(true) });` I get the error message `this.select() is not a function`.

This is my code:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.selected = false;
        this.draw();
        document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener("click", select(true));
    }

    draw() {
        //puts the element on the screen
    }

    select(_isSelected) {
        if (_isSelected == true) {
            this.selected = true;
            //this method also modifies the DOM element style
        }
    }

}

function start() {
    var firstRect = new Rectangle("sth");
}
```

The `start()` function is called at the end of HTML document.

Comment: You want: `'click', () => this.select(true)`

Comment: It works! haha I don't understand why though. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: See the linked canonicals